# Lots of errors popping up in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't know where to pinpoint the source of the errors in this code, hopefully someone can help. Errors are pasted after the source. It really was perfectly fine until maybe 2 seconds ago when I made a change that made eclipse want to terminate the currently running application.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;


public class AnimationManager {


    private JFrame appFrame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JPanel filePanel;
    private JPanel indexPanel;
    private JPanel propsPanel;
    private JPanel dataPanel;

    private JTree index;

    public AnimationManager() {
        appFrame = new JFrame("Animation Manager v0.1 by Firstmate");
        appFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                //save file

        });
        appFrame.setContentPane(createContentPane());
        createMenuBar();
        appFrame.setSize(1024, 768);
        appFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void createMenuBar() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    }
    private JPanel createContentPane() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(null);
        createFilePanel();
        createDataPanel();
        JSplitPane mainSplit = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true, filePanel, dataPanel);
        mainPanel.add(mainSplit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return mainPanel;
    }
    private void createFilePanel() {
        filePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        filePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 700));
        indexPanel = new JPanel();
        indexPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,350));
        Vector vector = new Vector();
        vector.add("One");
        vector.add("Two");
        index = new JTree(vector);
        index.setSize(300, 350);
        indexPanel.add(index);

        propsPanel = new JPanel();
        propsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 350));
        JSplitPane fileSplit = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, true, indexPanel, propsPanel);
        filePanel.add(fileSplit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private void createDataPanel() {
        dataPanel = new JPanel();
        dataPanel.setSize(724, 700);
    }
    public JFrame getAppFrame() {
        return appFrame;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
              //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AnimationManager am = new AnimationManager();
    }

}

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 75 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 75 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected   AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 75 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected   AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 75 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "{", invalid Type AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 42 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "{", invalid Type AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 42 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "{", invalid Type AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 51 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "{", invalid Type AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 51 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 38 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 38 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 50 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 50 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 67 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 67 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 84 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "JFrame", @ expected  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 72 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "JFrame", @ expected  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 72 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "JPanel", @ expected  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 42 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "JPanel", @ expected  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 42 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 39 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 39 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 51 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 51 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 68 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 68 Java Problem
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 39 Java Problem
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 39 Java Problem
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 68 Java Problem
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 68 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 25 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 33 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 33 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName   AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 72 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName   AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 72 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 72 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement  AnimationManager.java   /AnimationManager/src   line 72 Java Problem
```

Comment: I cannot answer it myself, but I was able to fix it. `I forgot a bracket here:
  appFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
    //save file
   }
  });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a bracket.

```
appFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                //save file
            **}** //Bracket here
});
```